# sails.js - internal 'production' settings or configuration

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I currently run a sails.js (0.12.3) application that has multiple production environments. I would like use a set of /config/env (ie /config/env/production-eu.js, /config/env/production-us.js) files instead of /config/env/development.js & /config/env/production.js with a manually managed local.js per server. The [sails documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration) states:

> The production environment is special-- depending on your configuration, it enables compression, caching, minification, etc.

I know 'production' means something when running a rails app. My question is - are there any internal/automagical settings/features that I would be missing by not using the recommended 'production' environment name running sails.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is - are there any internal/automagical settings/features that I would be missing by not using the recommended 'production' environment name running sails.js?

Yes, Environment (`NODE_ENV`) set to `production` has special settings.
See use of `production` in [Sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=production) & [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=production)

---

To address your use case, introduce a new environment variable say `NODE_LOCALE`.

```
NODE_LOCALE=us sails lift
```

OR

```
export NODE_LOCALE=us
sails lift
```

Require one of locale files in `production.js`, depending on environment:

```
var localeFile;
switch(process.env.NODE_LOCALE) {
  case 'eu':
    localeFile = './production-eu';
    break;
  case 'us':
  default:
    localeFile = './production-us';
}

module.exports = require(localeFile);
```

Comment: Excellent solution - useful even if it's not locale-specific (those were just examples). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the "production" environment it's an abstraction the resides on top of your two customizations.

I think that a better approach could be using the Node environment variables as a customization of your default production configuration.

You can use tools like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in order to inject the node environment variables into your sails application and then point them from your generic production configuration file.